# Date Time Selection Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to validate model by applying time series cross validation by leaving the last 5 weeks from the dataset.

Then forecast one week and add the week to your sample, one by one. Record the MSE and plot the forecast.

My problem is with the date and time in the CSV file that I have, and how to remove the last 5 weeks.
Dataset:

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://www.wu.ac.at/usr/ma/nloehndo/dmds/data/pm_25_weather.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the date which is 5 weeks before the last date in the index like this:

```
In [18]: data.index[-1] - pd.DateOffset(weeks=5)
Out[18]: Timestamp('2015-01-17 23:00:00')
```

Then create a boolean mask

```
cutoff = data.index[-1] - pd.DateOffset(weeks=5)
mask = data.index < cutoff
```

to segregate the data into two groups:

```
train, test = data.loc[mask], data.loc[~mask]
```

Comment: thanks it helped, but how do I forecast one week and then consider it as a feature for the next week and record mse and plot it?